# Akka-http logrequest not logging the request body

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using akka-http and trying to log a request on a specific path using [logrequest](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequest.html) :

```
 path(Segment / "account") { id =>
            logRequest("users/account", Logging.InfoLevel) {
              post {
              entity(as[Account]) { account => ???
                complete(HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NoContent))
              }
            }
          }
```

however on my log I see something like

```
HttpRequest(HttpMethod(POST),https://localhost:9009/api/users/123/account,List(Host: localhost:9009, User-Agent: akka-http/10.0.6, Timeout-Access: <function1>),HttpEntity.Chunked(application/json),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
```

what I am looking for is the exact request including the body (json) as it was sent by the requestor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"HttpEntity.Chunked(application/json)"` segment of the log is the output of [`HttpEntity.Chunked#toString`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.9/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity.scala#L512). To get the entire request body, which is implemented as a stream, you need to call [`HttpEntity#toStrict`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.0.9/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity.html#toStrict(timeout:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict]) to convert the `Chunked` request entity into a `Strict` request entity. You can make this call in a custom route:

```
def logRequestEntity(route: Route, level: LogLevel)
                    (implicit m: Materializer, ex: ExecutionContext) = {

  def requestEntityLoggingFunction(loggingAdapter: LoggingAdapter)(req: HttpRequest): Unit = {
    val timeout = 900.millis
    val bodyAsBytes: Future[ByteString] = req.entity.toStrict(timeout).map(_.data)
    val bodyAsString: Future[String] = bodyAsBytes.map(_.utf8String)
    bodyAsString.onComplete {
      case Success(body) =>
        val logMsg = s"$req\nRequest body: $body"
        loggingAdapter.log(level, logMsg)
      case Failure(t) =>
        val logMsg = s"Failed to get the body for: $req"
        loggingAdapter.error(t, logMsg)
    }
  }
  DebuggingDirectives.logRequest(LoggingMagnet(requestEntityLoggingFunction(_)))(route)
}
```

To use the above, pass your route to it:

```
val loggedRoute = logRequestEntity(route, Logging.InfoLevel)
```